# Pass column value as an existing table name in mysql database

Tags: mysql, r

```
dbWriteTable(channel, name = "infy", value = info, row.names = FALSE, append = TRUE)
```

in this code I'm mentioning `infy` as table name which exists in database. But wat I need is instead of that `infy` I should pass a column value of dataframe as table name.

If the table already exist then it should open and append the values in info dataframe to that particular table.

Answer (score 0):

This code solved my above problem

```
for(i in 1:5)
 {
  data<-sec_bhavdata_full[i,] 
  # View(data)
  data_database<-dbReadTable(channel,data$SYMBOL)
  # View(data_database)
  merged_data<-rbind.data.frame(data_database,data)
  #View(merged_data)
  #sym<-casefold(data$SYMBOL,upper=FALSE)
  # View(sym)
  dbRemoveTable(channel,tolower(data$SYMBOL))
  dbWriteTable(channel, name = data$SYMBOL, value = merged_data, row.names = 
  FALSE)
}
```